# throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer') in node.js

Tags: node.js, typeerror

I'm new to node js and started learning a week ago.

While creating a small server I got the below error:

_http_outgoing.js:543
    throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');
    ^

TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:543:11)
    at call_backfunction (/Users/Aman/Documents/learn/node/app3/server.js:36:8)
    at iterator (/Users/Aman/Documents/learn/node/app3/server.js:57:6)
    at /Users/Aman/Documents/learn/node/app3/server.js:68:6
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)

```
function loadAlbums(req, res){
    var call_backfunction = function(err, album_list){
        if(err){
            res.writeHead(503, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            res.end("There are no albums in folder. " + err + "\n");
        }
        else{
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/json"});
            res.end(album_list);
        }
    }

    albumLoader(req, res, call_backfunction);
}


function albumLoader(req, res, callback){
    var path = req.core_url.pathname.substr(1, 6);
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, files){
        if(err){
            callback(err);
            return;
        }   
        else{
            var dirs = [];
            (function iterator(i) {
                console.log(dirs);
                if(i>=files.length){
                    callback(null, dirs);
                    return;
                }
                fs.stat(path + "/" + files[i], function(err, stat){
                    if(err){
                        callback(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    else if(stat.isDirectory){
                        dirs.push(files[i]);
                    }
                    iterator(i+1);
                });
            })(0);          
        }
    });
}
```

Its working fine when I change callback parameter to

```
callback(null, dirs.toString());
```

I really didn't understand the logic here, why it needs string or buffer.

Comment: just now red somewhere that res.write() takes only string or Buffer parameter, is this the case with res.end() also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

res.end(data) (with the data argument specified) is an equivalent of res.write() and res.end(). res.write() only accepts a string or Buffer as it's argument. Read more [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback).

When you run this code, album_list is an array.

```
res.end(album_list);
```

After converting the dirs array, and consequently the album_list argument to a Buffer or a string you will not get this error.

It has to be a string or Buffer because the default encoding of the response body is utf8 character encoding.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue.

Can also help me with this below paragraph from the like you shared:

The first time response.write() is called, it will send the buffered header information and the first body to the client. The second time response.write() is called, Node.js assumes you're going to be streaming data, and sends that separately. That is, the response is buffered up to the first chunk of body.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You can call res.write() multiple times to create a response body before calling res.end(). I must confess I'm not sure how this works internally.